# Why the test outcome sometimes stays 'in progress' when I have saved 'passed'?

Tags: c#, testing, tfs

Here is a part of the code which is giving me a headache:

```
TestOutcome outcome = TestOutcome.Passed;
run.AddTestPoint(point, null);
run.Save();
ITestCaseResult result = run.QueryResults()[0];
result.Outcome = outcome;
result.Save();
point.State = TestPointState.Completed;
point.Save();
```

Sometimes it saves the outcome as 'passed', but sometimes as 'in progress'.  It is 50/50, more or less. Any ideas?

**EDIT**: Looks like it is doing *toggle* between 'in progress' and 'passed'. Strange.

Comment: Show us how you implemented `Save`.

Comment: I did not. The type of  `point` variable is `ITestPoint` and it is implemented by Microsoft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!

If you ever encounter something like this, please add :

```
result.State = TestResultState.Completed;
```

Before you save the result.